# GPG failing with no error for one of my encrypted files

Tags: ubuntu, gpg

I'm using `gpg` 2.2.20 to encrypt plain text password files using my PGP key on Ubuntu as well as OSX (both have the same PGP key). I've got a single encrypted file that won't decrypt in Ubuntu but it will decrypt in OSX. I've also got a bunch of files that decrypt fine in both.

Here's what I'm running (and the entire verbose output on linux):

```bsh
$ gpg --verbose -o bad.txt --decrypt bad.gpg 
gpg: public key is 7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: using subkey 7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX instead of primary key 5XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

And here's the output of the same command in OSX:

```bsh
gpg: Note: RFC4880bis features are enabled.
gpg: public key is 7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: using subkey 7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX instead of primary key 5XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: encrypted with rsa4096 key, ID 7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, created 2022-01-23
      "My Name <my-email@gmail.com>"
gpg: AES256.OCB encrypted data
gpg: original file name='FNnyaS-bad.txt'
```

On OSX the command also outputs the decrypted contents into `bad.txt` which isn't working in Ubuntu.

I've noticed a couple things:

1. OSX `gpg` outputs this message: `gpg: Note: RFC4880bis features are enabled.` which could be related.
2. OSX `gpg` is version 2.3.4 which is newer than Ubuntu `gpg` which is 2.2.20.

Can anyone explain what's happening here? It's strange that even in verbose mode the logs just end with no error. I can't seem to install a newer version of `gpg` on Ubuntu (at least with `apt`). Do I just need to be more careful about mixing `gpg` versions?

Comment: According to https://dev.gnupg.org/source/gnupg/browse/master/NEWS OCB (and EAX) was added in 2.3.0, so it won't be supported in 2.20.anything -- and according to packages.ubuntu.com even not-yet-final jammy (22.04) will only have gnupg 2.2.27 (but does have openssl 3.0.1!). This might use a new packet type the older version(s) can't even decode (rather than just an algo code they could skip); you might try `--list-packets` on both versions to see.

Answer (score 6):

I've spent good half of the day trying to figure out this error. As it first started to fail without errors on gopass.

What I've managed to find out is that the Ubuntu is able to encode message to macos and macos is able to decode it. When it does it reports: `gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data`

While when the same file  is encoded on macos during decoding gpg outputs `gpg: AES256.OCB encrypted data`

So @dave_thompson_085 had a good guess.

## Solution (update to answer above)

> **TLDR:** Disable AEAD in your key prefs by running `gpg --edit-key ...` and then `setpref SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 SHA1 AES256 AES192 AES ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed` then `y` then `save`. Then reencrypt your messages.

I've went to the bottom of this issue. CFB is not an AEAD algorithm it just indicate what cipher block was used. AEAD defines a cider block and a way to authenticate associated plain text like package headers etc. It is a faster alternative to MDC - Modification Detection Code.

GPG has no option to disable `AEAD` and force `MDC` if `AEAD` is enabled in your Key preferences, and it is set so by default when you generate a key with new gpg. The only way to fix the issue is to edit key preferences to remove any AEAD algorithms.

### How to edit key pref to make it compatible with gpg 2.2.x

Let's first make a small test to see that the AEAD is being used:

```
$ KEY=me@piotrczapla.com
$ echo test | gpg --encrypt --recipient $KEY | gpg --verbose --decrypt
...
gpg: AES256.OCB encrypted data
gpg: original file name=''
test
```

As you can see the OCB is being used.
Let's now edit the key preferences. You can show your current preferences with showpref

```
$ gpg --edit-key $KEY

gpg> showpref
[ultimate] (1). Piotr Czapla <me@piotrczapla.com>
     Cipher: AES256, AES192, AES, 3DES
     AEAD: OCB
     Digest: SHA512, SHA384, SHA256, SHA224, SHA1
     Compression: ZLIB, BZIP2, ZIP, Uncompressed
     Features: MDC, AEAD, Keyserver no-modify
```

The tweak the following command to match your prefs but disable AHEAD. It will ask you for confirmation before changing the prefs.  In may case this list did the trick: `setpref SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 SHA1 AES256 AES192 AES ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed`

Once you have your just confirm change and save your key.

```
gpg> setpref SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 SHA1 AES256 AES192 AES ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed

Set preference list to:
     Cipher: AES256, AES192, AES, 3DES
     AEAD:
     Digest: SHA512, SHA384, SHA256, SHA224, SHA1
     Compression: ZLIB, BZIP2, ZIP, Uncompressed
     Features: MDC, Keyserver no-modify
Really update the preferences? (y/N) y

sec  ed25519/285CE99FAA64E280
     created: 2022-07-20  expires: 2025-07-19  usage: SC
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  cv25519/C2C95918A535E298
     created: 2022-07-20  expires: 2025-07-19  usage: E
ssb  ed25519/CDEBF13E9DE11878
     created: 2022-07-21  expires: 2027-07-20  usage: A
[ultimate] (1). Piotr Czapla (api key used to decrypt gopass on less secure instances) <me@piotrczapla.com>

gpg> save
```

Then test that `aead` is not being used:

```
$ echo test | gpg  --encrypt  --recipient $KEY | gpg --verbose --decrypt
...
gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data
gpg: original file name=''
test
```

And observe how the default `CFB` is being selected.